# debug.keystore opening with asking Open with promp

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, md5-file

Hi from since morning i am trying to get MD5 finger print for Google API, Key but not able to get it,the main problem is i changed properties of debug.keystore file to **Open With Microsoft Word** 
so whenever  i am trying to get it from command prompt it opens in MS-Word in encoded format.
Please help me how can i get it.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This command line command also opens MS Word?

```
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore .android/debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

Comment: instead of `.android/debug.keystore` use your path to the debug.keystore